# Find rows with exact geography coordinates

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a SQL table with a geography column. When I look at one of the rows the geography shows as a long hex string: 0xE6100....C0.

I want to write a query that finds all other rows in my database that have this same value. How can I do this?

I tried adding `WHERE location = '0xE6100....C0'` with and without quotes but I get an error:

`Invalid operator for data type. Operator equals equal to, type equals geography.`

Note: I'm just doing this query in an ad-hoc fashion I'm not really looking for a optimal solution or a way to parameterize this in any way. I just have a row that I'd like to find related values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to use `.STEquals`
Check the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933809.aspx)